# Modelling atemporal causal link between two (or three) indices

Tags: factor-analysis, multivariate-analysis

I want to construct two (or three) indices with two sets of variables (say around fifteen variables in each set) and then examine the causal link between these two indices. For example, to test the hypothesis that first indices affect negatively the second indices, how I can build such a model and test this hypothesis? Is Structural Equation Modelling a way of doing this. Please note that Granger causality may not be suitable because I am looking at atemporal causal links. Please suggest something.

Comment: SEM is not a miraculous statistical procedure. Causality is inferred by design, not by statistics. If you don't have time information on the events (and only observe that they are correlated), it will be hard to determine for certain that one caused the other, and not vice-versa, or that they're not both caused by a third variable.